# How to share dependencies across regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

CDK does not support cross-region references:

```
Error: Stack "Sandbox/us-east-2/1" cannot consume a cross reference from stack "Sandbox". Cross stack references are only supported for stacks deployed to the same environment or between nested stacks and their parent stack.
```

However, some resources (ex: databases) are inherently global in use.  How do we manage global resources and their cross-region dependencies with CDK?

Comment: What do you mean? CloudFormation is regional service only. There is no such thing as cross-region reference in CloudFormation. Do you have an example of what you want to do?

Comment: I have a global DocDB, an ECR, and a VPC defined in a global stack. Then I have nested regional stacks that receive these global resources as props.  How can I similarly references the global objects required to configure regional resources?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not clear. What do you mean by "global stack"? CloudFormation is only regional.

Comment: Global meaning the resources defined in the stack are to be referenced globally.  For example, a database is commonly shared across multiple regions.

Comment: How did it go? You still don't know what you can do instead of cross-region references which are not supported in CloudFormation?

Comment: I guess I will break up my stacks and integrate with parameter store

Comment: I don't think your answer is accurate, as you can't pass resources across stacks of differing regions, and outputs can't be leveraged as db credentials aren't outputs

Comment: My answer tells you how to do it. Through custom resources. This is how it is done, if you don't pass them as input parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to make a "global" reference in a plain CloudFormation (CFN). CFN is a **regional service**, and you can't reference exported outputs from one stack in a stack deployed in a second region.

There are two solutions for that:

1. The "global" resources must be passed to other stacks as **input parameters**.
2. Create a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) to fetch the output values from stacks in other regions.

Comment: I'm currently passing them as props (I think that's what you mean by input parameters), but the compiler is detecting cross stack dependencies

Comment: @twinlakes  Most AWS resources are regional, so even if you pass them as parameters, you can't use them across-regions. You would have to construct custom resources to use them. But its probably easier to re-architect your solution, as its not supported by AWS if it depends on cross-region references.

Comment: What about for inherently global resources like a database, or a hub VPC that I set up peering to?

Comment: @twinlakes Cloudformation is regional. Rds databases are also regional, just like vpc. The main global service is IAM.

Comment: Then how do AWS services implement regional fault tolerance if you can't share a database between multiple front-end regions?

Comment: @twinlakes This is a topic for a different question in my view. Your current issue is about cloudformation and lack of cross region references.